# Systemd service to create a symlink

Tags: systemd

I would like to have Systemd manage the existence of a symlink.  The symlink should exist in `/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock` and point to `/var/run/proxysql/mysqld.sock`.  The reason for which is obvious/controversial (and I won't get into).  Lets look past that detail and focus on the solution being requested.

I have so far created this unit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqldsocket.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Create a symlink to the ProxySQL MySQL UNIX socket
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RuntimeDirectory=mysqld
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0775
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ln -s /var/run/proxysql/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
ExecStop=rm -f /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Running `systemctl start mysqldsocket.service` does create the symlink and `systemctl stop mysqldsocket.service` does delete it.  However systemd has no idea if the file actually exists, `systemctl status mysqldsocket.service` won't always match to reality.

```
# systemctl start mysqldsocket.service
# rm /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
# systemctl status mysqldsocket.service 
● mysqldsocket.service - Create a symlink to the ProxySQL MySQL UNIX socket
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysqldsocket.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Sun 2022-04-03 22:21:46 UTC; 14s ago
    Process: 750220 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ln -s /var/run/proxysql/mysqld.sock /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock (code=exited, status=0/SUCCE>
   Main PID: 750220 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Is there something I can add to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqldsocket.service` that tells systemd to verify that the symlink does indeed exist and report correct status based on that?